# 2nd match, match multiple criteria, no VBA function/VBA code

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Morning everyone.

I've got an array excel function which works based on 3 criteria as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('merged wz'!W:W,MATCH(1,('q log wz'!$C55='merged wz'!$M$1:$M$8000)*('q log wz'!$A55='merged wz'!$K$1:$K$8000)*(28='merged wz'!$P$1:$P$8000),0)),"No data")
```

now it works good for true and falses in the last part for one of the column datas where I need to return first match

```
(28='merged wz'!$P$1:$P$8000)
```

but this array will always have 2no trues and in other column I would like to modify this function so it replaces first true in array with false so it will return true only for the second match.

Any ideas how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: Hi, I use Excel 2019

Answer (score 1):

Just showing one way of dealing with what you are trying:

[image]

Formula (CSE-entered) in `D1`:

```
=INDEX(C1:C8,SMALL(IF((A1:A8="a")*(B1:B8="x"),ROW(C1:C8),""),2))
```

This will return the 2nd match where column A=='a' and B=='x'.

Comment: Thanks. I will attempt to use similar approach in my case.